# How to start jbpm as system's service in ubuntu?

Tags: redhat, ubuntu-18.04, jbpm, systemctl

I just downloaded jbpm server from [JBPM](https://www.jbpm.org/download/download.html).
it starts by running "jbpm-server/bin/standalone.sh" this. But i want to start jbpm as ubuntu's service like---> systemctl start jbpm.

can anyone provide me details to create startup script for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a file in your systemd directory, for example `/etc/systemd/system/change_me.service` and fill it with a basic setup like:

```
[Unit]
Description=Your service's description

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/executable.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then you should reload your systemd configuration in order to update it with the new service via

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

And then start it

```
sudo systemctl start change_me
```

If you want a more granular control over your systemd's service file you should read the man page via:

```
man systemd.service
```

Comment: What should i put in [Install] field....like can you elaborate "WantedBy=multi-user.target" this.

Comment: It just tells systemd to run your service whenver `multi-user.target` is launched. `multi-user.target` is just an alias to a default startup service ( https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html ). This way you can launch your service at startup!

Comment: Glad it helped! Mark this thread as resolved or accept the answer to help other people find it!